# Why doesn't the menu close after I open it, and click on an element?

Tags: wordpress, menu

Why doesn't the menu close after I open it, and click on an element? It just scrolls down to the section, and I have to click the X in order to close it.
Please help
Platform: Wordpress, Divi Theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a jquery code for you.

```
jQuery('.menu-item a').click(function(){
  jQuery('.et_slide_in_menu_container').removeClass( "et_pb_fullscreen_menu_opened et_pb_fullscreen_menu_animated" );
});
```

Try this

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks !!